# How and when to perform a two sample t-test or a two sample z-test?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I have a data set about 5,699 PhD students. The first column called "Year" is how many years it took for candidate to graduate with a Ph.D (1, 2,...14), the second column "Uni" is which university the student received the PhD, and the third column "Res" is residency of subject (permanent or temporary)

```
> head(mydata)
   Year     Uni       Res
1    1 Berkeley Permanent
2    1 Berkeley Permanent
3    1 Berkeley Permanent
4    1 Berkeley Permanent
5    1 Berkeley Permanent
6    1 Berkeley Permanent
```

I wish to see if there is a significant difference in the number of years it took for PhD students to graduate by residency. I'm assuming I must perform a two sample t-test or a two sample z-test. I know that one performs a z-test if the standard deviation of the population is known, and a t-test if it is not known. However, I have no information on whether these 5,699 students form a population or if they are samples from a larger population. Since I am not sure, should I perform the two sample t-test?

One of the assumptions of the two sample t-test and the two sample z-test is that the data must be normally distributed. Does this mean I have check if the number of years to graduate is normal for each group (permanent, temporary) or do I combine the data and check to see if the years to graduation is normal? What kind of tests do I use to check for normality in this case? Are there other assumptions I should be aware about?

Comment: Whether a group forms a sample or a population depends crucially on the intended scope of your inferences: are you aiming to describe these 5699 people or will you attempt to derive conclusions about a larger group of people from these data?  BTW, neither test assumes data are normally distributed.  You would benefit from reading some of our high-voted threads about these tests.

Comment: I'm wondering about the range and discreteness of the dependent variable  (Year).  If there are only a few values this variable can take, you might need an analysis appropriate for ordinal dependent variables... or maybe one appropriate for count variables.

Comment: @whuber: Doesn't t-test assume normality? The sample statistic in t-test follows t-distribution under the assumption of normality isn't it? Asymptotically it will follow normal but to get the sampling distribution isn't normality a required assumption?

Comment: @Dayne The t-test assumes the sampling distribution of the statistic is *sufficiently close* to a Student t to permit the use of the Student t CDF in converting the t-statistic to a p-value *for t-statistics close to the critical value.* These italicized conditions tend to hold for many underlying non-Normal distributions and typical critical values (like 5% and 1%), especially those distributions that aren't very skewed.

Comment: @whuber can you please cite some good source for this? Also, you say t-test *assumes* this. I think this may be a result found later. The original does assume normality, afaik.

Comment: @Dayne I can't remember where I saw the clearest account, but Chapter 1 of Mosteller & Tukey (1977), *Data Analysis and Regression,* has a nice discussion of the issues.

Comment: @whuber thanks  for the reference, but I am curious how is *sufficiently close* defined in this context.

Comment: @Dayne It depends on your needs.  You could ask similar questions of any quantitative theory: for instance, Newtonian mechanics is perfectly fine except at really tiny distances or relativistic speeds.  How tiny or how fast?  It depends on how accurate you need the results to be.

Comment: Ok. So I was thinking (also hoping) that there is some theoretical underpinning to this. But if it is that for many non-normal distributions,t-test gives *approximately* correct answer then it's a different story. I guess, in principle, we should continue to say that t-test *assumes* normality.